Python Multiprocessing - Manager Proxy - Return Proxy To Managed Object
Assume the following setup:
class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._x: str = ''

    def get_x(self) -> str:
        return self._x


class FooProxy(BaseProxy):
    _exposed_ = ['get_x']

    def get_x(self):
        return self._callmethod('get_x')


class FooManager:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._foos: list[Foo] = [Foo(), Foo()]

    def indices(self):
        return len(self._foos)

    def get_foo(self, index: int):
        return self._foos[index]


class FooManagerProxy(BaseProxy):
    _exposed_ = ['get_foo', 'indices']

    def indices(self):
        return self._callmethod('indices')  # OK

    def get_foo(self, index: int):
        return self._callmethod('get_foo', args=(index,))  # Want to return proxy ??


foo_manager: FooManager = FooManager()


def get_foo_manager():
    return foo_manager


class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass


MyManager.register('get_foo_manager', get_foo_manager, FooManagerProxy)

How can i return a FooProxy from the FooManagerProxy.get_foo function, so when calling that method from a client, i get a proxy for the foo object, instead of getting a copy of that object?
